# How does centering of a Tk canvas text widget work?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I noticed an artifact when placing a centered canvas text (\u25a1) widget above a centered rectangle widget with same x:

[image: Square character is not aligned with gray rectangle]

Having worked with font rendering once or twice I realize there are multiple possible definitions of "centered". Now I wonder which Tk canvas text uses.

In my previous projects I've used `(pen+text.advance)/2`, where text.advance is the *accumulated advance width* of each character. This is what I would assume Tk is using based on the behavior I'm experiencing.

However, another possible way to center text would be to center using the *accumulated bitmap coverage*, measured from the left-most character bitmap left edge to rightmost bitmap right edge. I believe it is more likely what I would want.

Q1: How is Tk canvas text centering supposed to work in terms of font metrics?

Q2: Is the behavior I'm seeing a bug, or possibly underspecified?

---

Edit: Working with it some more the square symbol is sometimes aligned with the rectangle, sometimes not. Probably some rounding error. Question is whether or not it is a bug.

---

Edit 2: Adding 0.5 to x seem to put the square in its right place. Maybe pixel origin is defined differently for rect and text?

Answer (score 1):

Tk uses the logical properties of the font to determine what space to give text. In particular, it asks the font engine to *measure* the length of a piece of text (typically in one font and without newlines or tabs) to determine the bounding box of that text. It then decides where that bounding box should be (depending also on the anchoring rules, the sizes of other lines, the justification rules, the rotation setting when on a canvas, and so on) and finally asks the font engine to draw the text within the box, i.e., from the origin point within the box (which isn't the top-left point IIRC, but might actually be the leftmost point on the baseline — I let Tk handle the details of this to be honest).

From there on, it's up to the font engine (which cares about the details of cumulative error, a non-trivial concern when text is at any angle not parallel to an edge of the window), and as long as it stays within the bounding box Tk is happy.

Tk's canvas works with floating point coordinates, but on most platforms it rounds those to integers when rendering. (The exception is on macOS, where the platform drawing engine itself accepts floating point coordinates and all graphical output on the canvas is subject to good subpixel rendering. This can cause something of a change in how canvases look on that platform, even though there's no change in model; arguably, that's closer to how they're supposed to look too, and you end up with the same sort of thing if you convert a canvas's display to embedded postscript.)

Comment: Interesting. Are you saying this *font engine* is to blame, provided by the platform, not Tk? Trying to nail out a course of action here